# WordPress error using kallyas-child theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming

I administrate a website that is built on WordPress 4.8.6. It uses the theme `kallyas-child`.

On rendering it raises the following error message.

```
TypeError: $(...).parent(...).parent(...).parent(...).closest(...).parent(...).attr(...) is undefined [more info] zn_script_child.js:3:19
window.onload<https://www.domain.tld/wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/js/zn_script_child.js:3:19
<anonym>https://www.domain.tld/wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/js/zn_script_child.js:1:17
```

I have no idea on how to debug that error message. Do you know the reason for that error? Or a way on how I could track that error down in WordPress?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable debug mode in wordpress you can use the global variable 'WP_DEBUG':

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

WP_DEBUG_LOG causes all errors to also be saved to a debug.log log file inside the /wp-content/ directory.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Here's the link to the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) on debugging your site.

Regarding the error-msg it looks like an attribute used in ../wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/js/zn_script_child.js in line 3 is undefined onLoad (when the window is loaded). I hope that will help you to find the problem/issue.